# windows phone ApplicationPolicy for in app payment

Tags: windows-phone-7, paypal, in-app-purchase, policy

I was wonder if it's possible to use PayPal mobile checkout directly in my wp7 app, as in-app payment gateway.
My concern it’s Microsoft marketplace application policy 2.1:

> “Your application must be fully functional when acquired from Windows
>   Phone Marketplace (except for additional data as permitted below).
>   Unless you have a pre-existing billing relationship with the user,
>   your application may not require the user to provide payment
>   information,within the application experience, to activate, unlock, or
>   extend usage of the application. “

Does this means I’m not allowed to use PayPal to make in-app purchasing?
Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

I think this policy only applies to your app. If you want to use PayPal

> to activate, unlock, or extend usage of the application

than it's not allowed. If you want to do other things which require PayPal the policy allows you to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The marketplace requirement menas that you must have that "pre-existing billing relationship with the user". It doesn't put any restriction on how you bill your users. You could, therefore use PayPal or any ither method available to you.

This requirement is partly to enforce the prevention of apps which have no functionality when downloaded from the marketplace, without paying for the content.

I would suggest contacting app hub support to further discuss your specific requirements if you need to or to confirm the exact meaning around what qualifies as a "pre-existing billing relationship".

Comment: So any kind of application based on monthly/yearly subscription cannot be uploaded in Marketplace?

Comment: Not unless you have the "pre-existing relationship". You'll need to ask Microsoft exactly what this means.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paypal. If you study the clause carefully, it states "Unless you have a pre-existing billing relationship with the user, **your application may not require the user to provide payment information,within the application experience,** to activate, unlock, or extend usage of the application."

f you do not have a pre-existing billing relationship with new users, all they need to do is to complete the payment information outside the app, for example get redirected to an external browser (Paypal) to input their details.

Hope this helps.